# Is there possible add aero effect in Control itself in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, blur

I have a **WriteableBitmap** that would display video in the Window.
Currently I need to **covert the subtitle** in the bottom.  I want to use a aero effect, but only cover the bottom of the WriteableBitmap.

Which mean, this is the original :

[image]

And I want to add a Grid Control which has aero effect, like This:

[image]

But I don't know how,  I already think about take the picture bottom place and use some effect , and then put it on the top,  But It looks a low performance for writableBitmap, because which mean it need to process 25 around picture every second...

**Update:**
Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgFrame"/>
</Grid>

private WriteableBitmap bitmap;

private void OnVideoFrameRunning(FrameArgs e)
{
   if (null == bitmap)
   {
       bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(e.Width, e.Height, 72, 72,PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);
       imgFrame.Source = bitmap;
   }

  bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, e.Width, e.Height), e.Buffer, e.Width * 3, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: The "aero effect" is created by DrawThemeTextEx(), DTTOPS.iGlowSize option.  The odds that you can use this in WPF are not good, this screams airspace issue.  OuterGlowBitmapEffect is gone in 4.0, you'll need to shoot for DropShadowEffect.

Comment: The question appears to have nothing to do with wpf. Consider dropping the tag. This is more image processing question than anything wpf (considering you're not satisfied with the only answer given below)

Comment: Do you have to have the text on the WritableBitmap or do you simply want to display the text over the control in a WPF window?

Comment: @MackieChan, The text from the video. I want to cover it. That's why I want blur effect on the video image but only the bottom.

Comment: @qakmak do you know what and where the subtitles are, or are you just covering a certain height on the bottom?

Comment: @MackieChan I don't know,  I just guess. It's always on the bottom, but I don't sure the exactly position.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="18"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               FontSize="40"
               Foreground="#444444"
               Text="Some Subtitles"
               Margin="0 0 0 20"/>
</Grid>
```

Radius="0":
[image: Radius="0"]

Radius="18":

[image: Radius="18"]

Comment: Looks great, but I need only cover the subtitle on the WritableBitmap.

Comment: @qakmak As is typical of SO, Please provide your code showing what have you done already and the relevant bits where you are struggling in your question. As such this is the expected answer and should be accept given your tags and general lack of information in question.

Comment: I think even I put my code you answer is too far, as I said ,  I need the blur area is in the image bottom,  not all image.  Now you give me the all blur Grid.

Comment: So what now? I've already put my code a few days ago. Your're answer still not correct, put the correct answer or delete it.

Comment: @qakmak maybe take a look at this? http://notes.ericwillis.com/2009/10/blur-an-image-with-csharp/

Comment: Do you want me convert the image to draw.image and convert to WPF image control again?  What a low performance....

Comment: So... where is the problem? Why don't you just blur a part of the image, basing on the code from Nikola.Lukovic? Just give this Grid a hight you need, and allign to bottom.

Comment: @swiszcz I believe he doesn't have the text that he needs blurred, he just has the video.  So he's trying to blur the bottom of the video.  So he can't use the Grid blur, as it won't have the text that he needs.